# Typewriter Script Stops Functioning after Run Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to get this typewriter function to run (please refer to JSFiddle below).

I set up an if-else statement so that when the user clicks on Biography the biography text is active and types itself out, and upon second click, the text becomes inactive and is erased. Ideally on a third click, the biography text will show up again, unfortunately this is when my code falls apart. It only runs once, and the text no longer shows up.

I tried console.logs and know that the DOM is registering when #bio has the class "active" attached to it, and when it does not, so I'm not sure why the typewriter script is not working the second time around.

```js
var str = "<p>This is biography text.</p>",
    i = 0,
    isTag, text;


$('#biog').click(function () {

    if ($("#bio").hasClass("active")) {
        $("#bio").removeClass("active");
        $("#bio").detach();
    } else {
        $("#bio").addClass("active");
        (function type() {
            text = str.slice(0, ++i);
            if (text === str) return;
            document.getElementById('bio').innerHTML = text;
            var char = text.slice(-1);
            if (char === '<') isTag = true;
            if (char === '>') isTag = false;
            if (isTag) return type();
            setTimeout(type, 1);
        }());
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
}
```

```html
<div id="biog"><a>Biography</a>
</div>
<div id="bio"></div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/droogist/20L8088r/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in you code.

- You are detaching element after one use, because of that the second time you try accessing it, it is not there.
- You are not resetting the variable `i` after one use.

So, use `$("#bio").html('');` instead of `$("#bio").detach();`

And also, add `i = 0;` in else part of your code.

Here is the updated JSFiddle, 
http://jsfiddle.net/20L8088r/2/